# PHP PDO query: fetch a field from the first row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve a specific field from the first row of my query results. The following works just fine...

```
$result = $db->query($query);

$firstrow = $result->fetch();
$desired_field = $firstrow["field"];
```

My question is, can i do this in one step without storing the first row of results in a variable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to? It's much cleaner this way.

Comment: its not the only column. I agree Jeremy, its only 2 lines, but I was wondering if there was a method that I am unaware of to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fetchColumn()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to return a single column from the next row in the result set. If there is only one column in the result set, do:

```
$desired_field = $result->fetchColumn();
```

If there are multiple columns in the result set, specific the numeric index of the one you want:

```
$desired_field = $result->fetchColumn(1);
```

Take notice of the warning provided in the `fetchColumn()` documentation:

> There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

Comment: is there something similar that I can pass an associative index? that would be what I a looking for

Comment: @Neil None that I know of, but the numeric index is deducible if you specify the fields in the query or (usually) if you know the column order in the table.

Comment: Awesome, so the index applies to the columns in the query result? so if i specify fields in the query I will not need to worry about the actual index of that field in the database?

Comment: @Neil Exactly. If your query is `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table` and you want to use `fetchColumn()` to get 'field3', use `fetchColumn(2)`. The indexing is zero-based, so 'field1' is at index '0'.

Comment: Perfect! I was worried about the field changing index in the database, but not anymore. Thanks George for your time.

Comment: @NeilHarlow if you expect only one field - why would you need an associative index anyway?

Comment: I only need the one field from the first row, however any additional rows returned by the query i need multiple fields. But maybe a separate query would remove that need ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `$firstrow = $db->query($query)->fetch()` but this is not good practice to do with functions that aren't guaranteed to return an object.

The query() function can return FALSE on error, and the dynamic call to fetch() would be a fatal error.  You can't call `->fetch()` on a scalar FALSE value.

For example, try the following and your script will explode:

```
$firstrow = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_that_does_not_exist")->fetch();
```

PDO does support a mode to throw exceptions instead of returning FALSE, so in that case you are guaranteed either `query()->fetch()` works, or else query() will throw an exception, so you will never reach the fatal error.  But you might not be using PDO's exception mode.

The answer from @GeorgeCummins points out that there's a `fetchColumn()` method that you can use once you have a PDOStatement object, that's a good way to get a single column.  If you only need one column, name that column as the *only* column in your select-list, and then always use `fetchColumn(0)`:

```
$oneValue = $db->query("SELECT oneColumn FROM table")->fetchColumn(0);
```

Otherwise if you use fetch(), this returns an array.  PHP 5.4 supports array dereferencing:

```
$oneValue = $db->query("SELECT oneColumn FROM table")->fetch()[0];
```

But if you're using PHP 5.3 or earlier this is not supported.  And I've never tried it with the array returned by PDOStatement so if it's actually returning an ArrayObject or something this might not work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This is guarantee to work if and only if your query is correct and there is at least one row data.

```
$db->query($query)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->field;
```

Comment: After I got downvote, I ran a test and it does work as expected.

Comment: I have updated the answer. However, I found it is rather strange that you will get downvote for answering a question with a untested code that I used to use it before. (the uncertainty is because I haven't tested the code, but at least it's based on my experience).